# C# - How to shrink SHA512 down to size

Tags: c#, security, encryption, passwords, hash

Based on a combination of previous answers, I was able to resolve an issue with outputting the appropriate characters for a hash. I am still having a problem with length, as the hash i am getting is much longer than the expected one from the documentation I am following. The api documentation says to use SHA512 and has "FA35A0194E3BE7024CEFB1839CBFC922" as the example parameter, but when I run my hash tester with a simple password like "test" to get a value to pass into it I get "EE26B0DD4AF7E749AA1A8EE3C10AE9923F618980772E473F8819A5D4940E0DB27AC185F8A0E1D5F84F88BC887FD67B143732C304CC5FA9AD8E6F57F50028A8FF" - which is obviously much longer than what I need.

FYI, here is what I'm using to do this:

```
byte[] hashedPassword = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA512").ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes("test"));
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hashedPassword).Replace("-", ""));
```

Hopefully someone out there has more experience than I do (more than none) with this hash stuff. Is it normal to shrink a value like this somehow or take a certain part of it? I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: SHA512 produces a 512-bit hash. 512 bit = 8 byte. Hex uses 2 characters per byte. So the hex hash will have 128 characters. You can't shrink this without truncating the hash.

Comment: Can you give a link to the documentation?

Comment: SHA-512 should generate 512-bits = 64 bytes. Your sample is 32 characters of hex = 16 bytes, so that can't be right. AFAIK there's no standard way to reduce a hash down like this; you could e.g. take the first 16 bytes or xor together four groups of 16 bytes but you'd just be guessing. Your documentation is either wrong or incomplete: you should talk to your supplier for help.

Comment: It's also possible they just didn't bother printing a huge long random string in the documentation as a sample value, and the longer value is actually correct. But you'd have to ask them.

Comment: The longer one definitely doesn't work - I'm using my own username/password for the third-party app and it's not accepting the longer hash.

Comment: dsolimano - unfortunately I cannot because its not public, but I could try to copy/paste the relevant portion if that would help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You asked for a 512 bit hash. 512 bits is 64 bytes. 64 bytes written in hex is 128 characters. I'm therefore not understanding why you think something is wrong here.

> which is obviously much longer than what I need.

Why is that obvious?

If it is much longer than what you need then **why did you ask for a 512 bit hash in the first place**?

> Is it normal to shrink a value like this somehow or take a certain part of it?

**Absolutely not**.

> I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Hire a professional who specializes in writing security software, who can write the software for you and train you in its correct maintenance. You do not know enough about writing secure software to do so successfully. Writing security systems is *one of the hardest things you can do* in any language; it takes years of training and experience to write a system that is actually secure against attack.

Comment: @james: Are you sure that your system is expecting a SHA512 hash? If it is expecting 128 bits, not 512, then maybe it is expecting an MD5 hash.  (Note that MD5 is considered to be a weak algorithm for some applications these days; if you can use SHA512 or SHA256, you should.)

Comment: The only thing I'm sure of is that it needs the smaller one because the longer one doesn't validate correctly when I use a test login.

Comment: @james: If your question is really "how do I make this poorly documented legacy system work" then I think that StackOverflow is unlikely to help you. Find the person who wrote the legacy system and ask them, or read the source code of the legacy system, or reverse-engineer the source code from the binary, or whatever.

Comment: THANK YOU ERIC LIPPERT YOU ARE A LIFESAVER! It worked when I switched to using MD5 instead of SHA512!!!

Comment: Truncating hashes isn't that uncommon. A truncated hash should still have the same properties as a hash designed with that size. While using different initial states for different sizes is recommended, it only matters in very specific scenarios. For example SHA-384 is a truncated SHA-512 with different initialization values.

Comment: In the context of password hashing plain sha-512 and plain md5 are pretty much equally bad. Both of them have no fast pre-image attack, both aren't salted, and both are fast. Some form of dictionary attack is the most efficient attack, and that will be only slightly slower for SHA-512 than for md5. I recommend migrating the system to bcrypt or pbkdf2, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

[FIPS PUB 180-4](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) allows truncated hashes.
The main reason for adding truncated versions was that SH512 is faster than SHA256 on some CPUs, hence truncating SHA512 can be a interesting option. However, the standard uses different initial values for truncated hashes.
This means you can't just take an off the shelf SHA512 implementation and truncate the result.

Comment: +1 interesting but this is for a login token: when you're hashing a login token you normally want slower hashes not faster hashes.

Comment: @Rup Well, the question is about how to truncate SHA512 and apparently nobody here reads standards. Anyway, if the OP could choose his own algorithm then he might use an iterated hash that which can be optimized for the target architecture, so that an attacker using different hardware does not get a big advantage.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks especially for linking th FUPS publication

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you figured this out, but you could convert each two-byte hex char into a single-byte.  It will not look like a standard hash but it will be the size that you are expecting.